# How much is a boat trip from Venezuela to Trinidad?

Tags: ferries, south-america, caribbean, venezuela, trinidad-and-tobago

I want to go from Venezuela (Guiria) to Trinidad by boat. Unfortunately I can't find any detailed information about prices and so on. The only thing I could find is that the boat leaves from Guiria in Venezuela every Wednesday.

Is there anyone who has some more information?

Answer (score 6):

There a ferry mentioned on the [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Chaguaramas/G%C3%BCiria) site which also mentioned that the tickets for the ferry can be bought on [Pier1TT](http://www.pier1tt.com/index.php), which appears to be in the process of upgrading, so they give a phone number to call.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to phone the ferry agency. A one-way ticket is about 6,500 Bolivares Fuertes (including taxes) <sup>(`USD` $1,035, `EUR` €755)</sup>. Round-trip has a cost of about 13,000 Bolivares Fuertes. <sup>(`USD` $2,070, `EUR` €1,515)</sup>

But a flight (for example from Margarita Island) is much cheaper. A Round-trip from Margarita Island to Port of Spain is about 5,000 Bolivares Fuertes <sup>(`USD` $795, `EUR` €580)</sup>. One-way is about 3,000 Bolivares Fuertes. <sup>(`USD` $475, `EUR` €350)</sup>

(Prices: Dec. 2013)

Answer (score 4):

Ferry service has been discontinued from Chaguaramas (Trinidad) to Guiria (Venezuela) as of June 1st 2014...

http://www.pier1tt.com/index.php/ferry

http://www.guardian.co.tt/news/2014-05-23/ferry-service-venezuela-will-end-june-1

Answer (score 2):

OOPS, a bit of humor from above!! Someone slipped a digit, or two, [here](http://www.pier1tt.com/index.php/ferry). **The Ferry isn't U.S.$2,000+. It's closer to U.S.$200. round trip.** (The poster confused TT$ with U.S.$, or slipped a digit in her conversions.) Or the prices have dropped ~90% in a year.....not!!

[image: TSE21942 example]

Comment: Do you have a source for these lower prices? It would be good to confirm it one way or the other!